# How to config Angular ui-router to not use strict URL matching mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

ui-router's version 0.2.11 introduced [option to turn off strict URL matching](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases/tag/0.2.11), but I can't figure out how to actually use it.

I've tried standard config as they use [in tests](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/a3e21366bee0475c9795a1ec76f70eec41c5b4e3#diff-e3de923a70a1e1f037f2cffd755ab70bR19):

```
app.config(function ($urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {
  $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.caseInsensitive(true);
  $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
});
```

None of those settings work, so I guess I'm either doing something wrong or it's bugged. There's also seem to be no documentation about it.

Comment: Is there an equivalent github issue open? (I can't seem to get this to work either)

Comment: @Nate https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1395 It should be fixed in master. I'm waiting for next release to test it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this was fixed in 0.2.12.

That said, I ran into this problem in 0.2.15. It turns out that you need to configure the `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider` BEFORE the `$stateProvider`.

i.e. the following code will NOT work:

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'loginController as loginCtrl'
});
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.caseInsensitive(true);
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
```

You have to configure the `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider` first, like this:

```
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.caseInsensitive(true);
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false); 
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'loginController as loginCtrl'
});
```

Comment: Using Ui Router 0.2.15 & AngularJS v1.4.7, this does not work.

Comment: @mcranston18 This works with angular-ui-router 0.2.15 and AngularJS 1.4.5. I doubt that it would have broken in 1.4.7, so check to see if there is something else you are missing.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. It seems it was really fixed. However, there seems to be a new bug which prevents me to configure `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider` in root module. As a workaround I'm setting it in first child module that's required by the root one.

Comment: In the end it might be the same scenario you describe.

Comment: @OndrejSlinták No worries about the late response - I was mostly posting this for the benefit of people like me who had the same problem. I appreciate the answer though :). However, I'm not experiencing the same bug you are with the root module. There might be something else going on.

Answer (score -6):

use like this

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider",
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        return $routeProvider.when("/", {
            redirectTo: "/signin"
        })
        .when("/dashboard", {
            templateUrl: "App/views/Dashboard/dashboard.html",

        }).when("/signup", {
            templateUrl: "App/views/signup/signup.html",
            resolve: {
                permission: function (authorizationService, $route) {
                    return authorizationService.permissionCheck("signup");
                },
            }
        })
.when("/myAccount", {
            templateUrl: "App/views/myAccount/myAccount.html",
            resolve: {
                permission: function (authorizationService, $route) {
                    return authorizationService.permissionCheck("myAccount");
                },
            }
        })
        .when("/signin", {
            templateUrl: "App/views/signin/signin.html",
            resolve: {
                permission: function (authorizationService, $route) {
                    return authorizationService.permissionCheck("SKIP");
                },
            }
        })
```

Comment: This answer uses `angular-route`, but the question is related to `angular-ui-router`.